# How can i use 'this' in 'export const'?

Tags: javascript, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm build a store, and want to make action generator or others with a plugin.
On there met a problem. Because of `this`.
That is impossible thing on Nuxt & Vuex?

I posted plugin's source code ( with some black box )
My final goal is `generateActionList` with configuration object

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  const callAxios = (/* params */) => { /* some codes */ }
  const generateAction = (config) => {
    return (context, payload) => callAxios(/* params */)
  }
  const generateActionList = (config) => { // <= it's my Goal
    const actions = {}
    for (const [key, config] of Object.entries(conf)) {
      actions[key] = generateAction(config)
    }
    return actions
  }
  inject('storeUtil', {
    callAxios,
    generateAction,
    generateActionList
  })
}
```

if have some solution, please talk to me.

**i saw, 'this' is only lexically available on document.**

ps) https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `this`…? It’s not very obvious what the issue is.

Comment: @deceze sorry for late. i added sample source on codesandbox. i hope you understand, what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store is a module, not an instance of a class, so no `this`.

Instead of `...this.$storeUtil`, get it from Vue directly.

```
Vue.prototype.$storeUtil
```

It might also be available at `Vue.$storeUtil`.  If not, you could always init it there in `storeUtil`.

As an reference, this is how `filters` are reused outside of a component.

If it was never registered as `prototype`, you can just import it directly.

```
import storeUtil from '../storeUtil'
//...
[...storeUtil]
///...
```